# mailto: and tel: scheme with image in anchor tag on mobile web

Tags: android, html, anchor, mailto, tel

I have anchor tags positioned absolutely (one next to the other horizontally) at the bottom right corner of the page. One of the anchors is a mailto: link and the other is a tel: link. Each contains an image instead of text. Neither seem to work appropriately on my Android device. I can select each link, but only when I long-press do I get the option to call the number or send an email. If I get rid of the images and use the actual text for the phone number and email, the appropriate action happens. Is there some nuances I'm not aware of when it comes to making phones acknowledge phone numbers and emails that aren't actual text?

```
<a class="emailTag" href="mailto:myEmail@gmail.com">
     <img src="email_img.png" alt="myEmail@gmail.com" />
</a>
<a class="phoneTag" href="tel:1234567890">
     <img src="phone_img.png" alt="1234567890" />
</a>
```

I've also tried removing the img tag and setting the background-image for the anchor tags instead, but I get the same result.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have your problem on my 2.2 device.
Have you tried to make a simple test to avoid any side effects from your other css/js ?

Google in its mobile search results is doing this: `<div onclick="window.location.href = 'tel:0123456789'" >0123456789</div>`

It might work for you.